How to remove pam_tally, pam_tally2, and replace with pam_faillock? Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04
Anyone have guidance, step-by-step commands to properly remove both tally files and replace with faillock? I've seen topics on this on the forum, but none with actual commands to use. I'm trying to upgrade from 20 to 22 and run into the below error d-release-upgrade upon reboot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
You are using pam_tally or pam_tally2 in your configuration. 

The pam_tally and pam_tally2 modules have been removed from PAM. You 
are using one of these modules in your PAM configuration in 
/etc/pam.d. You must remove the uses of these modules before PAM can 
be upgraded; including these modules in your PAM configuration after 
the upgrade will stop users from being able to log into the system. 

Consider the pam_faillock module as a replacement for pam_tally.* 

